Opening a COM port in C++ with number higher than 9
I was having problems with opening COM ports with number greater than 9,
which brought me to this article
that states to specify the serial port as \\.\COM10.
This worked for me, and there were some explanations  here.
But I wish to know the details on where I can find the \.\ mapped at NT object space.
Where can I find the mapped data?
Is there a chance Microsoft would change this kind of a situation?

Some names are reserved, and others are "free". Adding more reserved names now would be a compatibility disaster.

This article Win32 Device Namespaces and the following NT Namespaces are probably the summary. I don't think that's likely to change.

Neither Windows nor Microsoft have anything to do with this.  These DOS device names are created by the device driver for these ports, it uses DefineDosDevice() to do so.  There is little commonality between drivers, but in general you can use Device Manager to see the assigned names.  Sometimes a driver offers a configuration page to select the first port number to assign.  The device manufacturer's user manual is the ultimate resource.
